# 2table data sum and show order by product name

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table. one is "goods receive" table. another is "product_use_for" table.

I need sum (goods_receive.quantity)  and sum (product_use_for.quentity)
and show it order by product name.

Actually I am new in php.I am confuse about this problem. I will lot of happy if anyone help me. please.

Please see this image >>

[image]

Comment: $sql="SELECT goods_receive.p_name, sum(goods_receive.quantity) as qua,sum(product_use_for.quantity) as use_qua  FROM goods_receive ,product_use_for
GROUP BY goods_receive.p_name";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, so that you'll get rows in the result even when there are no matches in the `product_use_for` table. And you need to do one of the sums in a subquery, otherwise you'll multiply the sum by the number of rows in the other table.

```
SELECT gr.p_name AS product_name, SUM(gr.quantity) AS stock_quantity, IFNULL(puf.quantity, 0) AS use_quantity
FROM goods_receive AS gr
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_name, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
           FROM product_use_for
           GROUP BY p_name) AS puf
ON gr.p_name = puf.p_name
GROUP BY gr.p_name
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78f28/3)